# It's possible to use the ibm-watson Assistant2 APIs from the browser?

Tags: browser, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm trying to use the Assistant2 APIs inside my Web Application (Angular CLI project) with the ibm-watson library and the suggested Webpack Configuration.

But at runtime I get different CORS policy errors calling the Assistant2 APIs.

So it's possible to use the Assistant2 APIs via browser?? Or calls must be all made server side to avoid the CORS policy errors?

Comment: Could you share more details about the `CORS` errors and about the way how are you invoking the `v2 API`?

Comment: You could found other details [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/issues/884)

Comment: So then probably this question should be answered there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Watson Assistant provides `REST API` that can be called from anywhere where there is access to `IBM` Cloud (which bacicaly means access to internet) - so from browser as well.

Now, while you can call the Watson Assistant `REST API` directly from the client-side browser, sometimes it might be beneficial to have a server doing the actual call as when you call the REST API from the browser then the user has access to the request and the response from the system. This means the user has access to `context` part of the dialog response which in some cases might not be desired (depends on the stuff that the author is storing in the context).